# Nvidia CUDA installation issues broken cache

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management, cuda

On the command `$ sudo apt-get install cuda` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cuda is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-opencl-icd-346 (>= 346.46) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I used this command `$ sudo apt-get -f install` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer     required:
  linux-image-generic
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
    The following extra packages will be installed:
  nvidia-opencl-icd-346
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-opencl-icd-346
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
30 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,829 kB of archives.
After this operation, 26.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 293998 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-opencl-icd-346_346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-opencl-icd-346 (346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-opencl-icd-346_346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd', which is also in     package nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-opencl-icd-346_346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I was trying to install Nvidia's drivers and CUDA however while installing CUDA. It shows broken cache and I can't repair it using the commands given.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to follow the official documentation from NVIDIA. To install CUDA on your laptop, follow this [guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf).

Comment: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-opencl-icd-346 (>= 346.46) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: What do you get when you try the `apt-get remove nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates` command ?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: How about a `sudo apt-get install nvidia-opencl-icd-346`

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-opencl-icd-346_346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd', which is also in package nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-opencl-icd-346_346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Join me in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25634/apt-get-isssue